trying to load each elements of list from separate yaml files into parent yaml
In Spring Cloud Gateway, we have too many routes in one application yaml. I am trying to break them into individual routes and import them into main/parent yaml.
Tried below approach of spring.profile.include but it is only loading the last route definition (instead of all those defined). Code sample below
File 1: application-route1.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: employee-route
          uri: http://localhost:8085
          predicates:
            - Path=/employee/**

File 2: application-route2.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: consumer-route
          uri: http://localhost:8086
          predicates:
            - Path=/consumer/**

Main Parent File:
spring:
  application:
    name: edge-gateway-service
  profiles:
    include: > 
      route1,
      route2

Here only route2 is loaded.
Appreciate any help/suggestions

The issue is that spring external configuration does not allow to override collection properties partially. And spring cloud gateway unfortunately does not have any other way to configure routes.
However, you can customise the configuration yourself. You can check a simple example in this repo.
The main idea is to replace collection definition with a map one. In your example, we have a route
routes:
    - id: employee-route
      uri: http://localhost:8085
      predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**

and we want to convert it to a map, so we can append new routes by including them from other files:
routes:
    employee-route:
      uri: http://localhost:8085
      predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**

To achieve that, firstly we need to declare a bean for the new configuration:
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinition;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Component
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cloud.gateway")
public class CustomRouterProperties {

    @NotNull
    private Map<String, RouteDefinition> routes;

    public @NotNull Map<String, RouteDefinition> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setRoutes(@NotNull Map<String, RouteDefinition> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

}

And declare our routes using RouteDefinitionWriter:
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinition;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionWriter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
public class CustomRouteConfig {

    public CustomRouteConfig(RouteDefinitionWriter writer, CustomRouterProperties properties) {
        Map<String, RouteDefinition> routes = properties.getRoutes();
        for (Map.Entry<String, RouteDefinition> entry : routes.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            RouteDefinition definition = entry.getValue();
            writer.save(Mono.just(definition).map(route -> {
                route.setId(key);
                return route;
            })).subscribe();
        }
    }

}

